# APEX Application ORDS_VERSION missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am setting up Oracle APEX application on Amazon Linux 2 and AWS Oracle RDS. while installing ORDS am getting below error.

ORDS_VERSION is missing