# ORDS_VERSION does not exist

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

While trying to install ORDS 20.4 I keep getting this error. Ords_version does not exist. I have already tried 4 times to install from scratch. My problem is similar to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726119/apex-application-ords-version-missing) but Im working on windows server 2012
[image: my error]

I have APEX 20.2 installed. My ORDS config directory is in c:\ords\conf I know it's recommended to set it up outside of the ORDS directoy, but Im working on a test environment. Does that have something with the issue im having?

Comment: My Oracle Support says that previous unsuccessful installations left *garbage* behind. Connect to SQL*Plus as SYS user and drop users ORDS_METADATA and ORDS_PUBLIC_USER (both with the CASCADE option). See document ID 2704538.1 for more info.

Comment: I've already tried, and it says that these users don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

just run this on admin cmd

```
java -jar ords.war uninstall
```

after u finshing this u will run this again

```
java -jar ords.war install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).